# Can I influence the address malloc returns on Linux?

Tags: c, linux, memory, malloc

I am currently trying to find a way to only get return addresses in a specific 1GB range using malloc under linux. 
Is there a way to either tell the kernel what (virtual) addresses to use or to know for a process which addresses can be returned?
I am running a 32bit Linux on an ARM based system (SoC).

I read about page directories. Could they be a way to solve this, for example by making only one or two page directories available to the process?

Comment: Not straightaway... try `mmap()`.

Comment: If you can enable memory overcommit, you might be able to just `malloc()` a large enough chunk to push the effective addresses returned from later calls into your desired 1GB range.  That might have undesired side effects, though, such as triggering the OOM killer.  And, depending on the implementation, it might not work at all.

Comment: Why do you care what addresses it returns? Maybe this is an XY problem?

Comment: @Barmar I need to be able to use addresses much narrower than 32 bit. When I know that the first let's say 5 bit will always be the same in my process I don't have to save them thousands of times

Comment: Sounds like you should just allocate a single large block of memory, and then manage the addresses inside it yourself.